# Yeoman/Grunt - Compiling SASS files in subfolder

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, gruntjs, yeoman

This is my folder structure:

[image]

All the `sass` files that are in the `styles` folder (e.g. `newStyles.sass`) are being compiled, but the `sass` files in the `myUi` folder (e.g. `nuclearMed.sass`) are not.

I changed to `{,*/}*` with `/**/*` in my `Gruntfile.js`, but it is still only looking one-level down. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

This is my `Gruntfile.js`

```
// Generated on 2013-08-28 using generator-webapp 0.4.1
'use strict';
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;
var lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({port: LIVERELOAD_PORT});
var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
  return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  // show elapsed time at the end
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  // load all grunt tasks
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // configurable paths
  var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,
    watch: {
      coffee: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:dist']
      },
      coffeeTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/**/*.coffee'],
        tasks: ['coffee:test']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/**/*.css'],
        tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      jade: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.jade'],
        tasks: ['jade']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
        },
        files: [
          '.tmp/**/*.html',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.sass',
          '.tmp/styles/**/*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/**/*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              lrSnippet,
              mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
              mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
              mountFolder(connect, 'test'),
              mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.dist)
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
      }
    },
    jade: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          pretty: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '.tmp',
          src: '*.jade',
          ext: '.html'
        }]
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
      },
      all: [
        'Gruntfile.js',
        '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/**/*.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
        'test/spec/**/*.js'
      ]
    },
    mocha: {
      all: {
        options: {
          run: true,
          urls: ['http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>/index.html']
        }
      }
    },
    coffee: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
          src: '**/*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/scripts',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      },
      test: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'test/spec',
          src: '**/*.coffee',
          dest: '.tmp/spec',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/**/*.js',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '**/*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },
    // not used since Uglify task does concat,
    // but still available if needed
    /*concat: {
      dist: {}
    },*/
    'bower-install': {
      app: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
      }
    },
    // not enabled since usemin task does concat and uglify
    // check index.html to edit your build targets
    // enable this task if you prefer defining your build targets here
    /*uglify: {
      dist: {}
    },*/
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/**/*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/**/*.*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      },
      html: '.tmp/index.html'
    },
    usemin: {
      options: {
        dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      },
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/**/*.css']
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '**/*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp',
          src: '*.html',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
    // Put files not handled in other tasks here
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'images/**/*.{webp,gif}',
            'styles/fonts/**/*.*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '**/*.css'
      }
    },
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass',
        'jade',
        'coffee:dist',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'coffee',
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'coffee',
        'compass',
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin',
        'htmlmin'
      ]
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'open',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'mocha'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'jade',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem

"Compass operates on a folder level. Because of this you don't specify any src/dest, but instead define the sassDir and cssDir options."

```
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/**/*.js',
    cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
```

Globbing isn't supported by the sassDir config var. You can however use globbing in the specify config if needed:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#specify

Comment: I tried adding the following to the `compass options` 1) `specify: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/myUi/*.sass',` 2) `specify: 'nuclearMed/app/styles/myUi/*.sass',` 3) `specify: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/myUi/**/*.sass',` 4) `specify: 'nuclearMed/app/styles/myUi/**/*.sass',`. None of these worked.

Comment: did you make sure to change the sassDir to just point to the top level folder, and to restart the compass watch after editing the config file? I don't think you should need a specify config rule if you just want to handle all files and subfolder files. It could potentially also be something with compass, and it might help to `npm uninstall grunt-contrib-compass` and then install it again

Comment: I tried everything you suggested. It still doesn't work.